# Understanding the measurement error in Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm for non-linear least square

Tags: least-squares, error, covariance-matrix

I have been reading [this](http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/ce281/lm.pdf) pdf on LM algorithm and I have been having trouble understanding a few parts of it. For example, in the Introduction:

> where $σ_{y_i}$ is the measurement error for measurement $y(ti)$

What exactly is meant by this measurement error and why does it have the symbol of the standard deviation? Is there a formula for this measurement error for $y_i$ ?

> Typically the weighting matrix $W$ is diagonal with $W_{ii} = 1/σ^2_{y_i}$ , More formally, $W$ can be set to the inverse of the measurement error covariance matrix

How do we visualize the covariance matrix of the error? And how is a diagonal matrix produced by taking inverse of this covariance matrix? And what is the role of $σ_{y_i}$ in this matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an association between the error of the measurement and the width of the distribution of measurements. I don't know of an official source where it is written down to reference it. In every natural science and engineering this implicitly used like this.

It is assumed that the measurements have a fixed and homoskedastic distribution, so a single value is sufficient for the variation. In the case of a Gaussian distribution, it is obvious to use the standard deviation. But for every other (well behaved) case, you can use principally use a transformation; but the shorthand is also just the standard deviation $\sigma$. So it's the usual formulation for the second central moment of the distribution:
$$\sigma_i^2 = \int (y_i- \hat{y_i})^2y_i() dy_i$$
(for a distribution $y_i()$ and its central value $\hat{y_i}$)

For the weighting matrix, the general case is the inverse covariance matrix. For "visualization", you can start with the most simple case: if you chose a diagonal matrix, the $\chi^2$ is simply the squared sum of deviations divided by the variance -- the inverse elements of the covariance matrix. You can think of these inverse variances $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$ as weights.

A non diagonal covariance matrix simply means that the measurements are not independent from each other, but have a mixed expression. You might know the expression and could diagonalize it, but you don't need to. The matrix multiplication expression of the $\chi^2$ formula entirely takes it into account. You can refer to a standard book of applied statistics, depending on your field.

The elements of the covariance matrix are computed pairwise:
$$cov(y_i, y_j) = \sigma_{i,j} = \int (y_i-\hat{y_i})(y_j-\hat{y_j}) dy_idy_j $$
First of all you can see that the diagonal elements are the variances, $cov{i,i} = \sigma_i^2$. And the off-diagonal elements are values that describe the kind of average deviation from the mean value: a positive number means that if you go above the mean value in one variable, the other variable will be distributed around a higher value than its central value. If the covariance value is smaller than zero, you expect values smaller than the central value in the second variable, if you still chose higher values than the central value in the first.

For a plot of this, simply look at the first image in the wikipedia entry on [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance).

Comment: How I'm trying to imagine it is instead of thinking of all the $y_i$ 's as values of a random variable $y$ , in the general case, each $y_i$ is an independent random variable with its own distribution and standard deviation. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Think of the case where you might measure something like the polar coordinates. You might have different devices for the angle and the distance, with different associated errors. And you might want to extract the best parameters in cartesian coordinates -- and directly you could derive the covariance matrix by analytical means.

Comment: Another thing. The covariance matrix in the general case seems to be diagonal as well, since we are taking $W$ as the inverse of the cov matrix, whose diagonal entries are the ${\sigma_i}^2$. If so, then are we assuming the $cov(y_i, y_j) = 0$ for all $i \neq j$ ?

Comment: In the general case, the covariance matrix isn't diagonal. But if you design your measurement carefully, you can build this in. In the case of a diagonal covariance matrix, all non-diagonal elements are zero. To invert the matrix, it doesn't have to be diagonal; that just makes it rather simple and in case of a numerical expression (e.g. automation with computers) very fast and accurate.